# Lashon hara l'toeles, with ulterior motives

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, chofetz-chaim, lo-taamod-al-dam-reyecha

The chafetz Chaim writes in *Hilchos Lashon Hara* (10:2) that one of the conditions of being allowed to relate *lashon hara l'toeles*, (for example to save someone from getting hurt), is that the person relating it must have intention only for the purpose of the *toeles* and nothing else. It would seem from this that if he has other intentions he is forbidden to relate the lashon hara even for the purpose of saving someone from getting hurt.

In *Hilchos Issurei Rechilus* (9:2), the Chofetz Chaim also lists this condition, regarding *rechilus letoeles*, but in the *Be'er Mayim Chaim* he writes that even if one has other (non-toeles) intentions, he must still relate the *rechilus*. because of the mitzvah of *Lo sa'amod al dam re'acha*, (not standing by to save someone), but he should try as hard as possible to relate it for the positive *toeles* purpose.

Does this apply only to *recilus*? If yes why? What's the difference? If it applies to lashon hara too, why does the Chafetz chaim say it only in *hilchos rechilus*, and not by *lashon hara*??

Answer (score 1):

Ask your LOR but  it  seems  to me that the Halacha  applies equally. However the situations the CC is discussing are not the same.

In  the case of  Loshon  Hora the CC is discussing, after the fact, knowledge when the damage has already been done. The only remaining  recourse is taking him to Beis  Din to try to get repaid for damages.

In the case of Rechilus the CC is discussing knowledge of *future* damage that will be caused to someone by doing something as serious as partnering with someone else .In such a case it would  be a violation of " Lo sa'amod al dam re'acha not to speak up.

A person with knowledge of future harm usually  has more of an obligation to speak up than someone who has knowledge of past harm because there is a much more clear Toelis in  doing so (an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of  cure) Therefore by Rechilus the CC stresses that just because you hate someone  you aren't absolved from *Lo sa'amod al dam re'acha* You  should force yourself to not only speak  out of hate. Conversely  by  Loshon  Hora  there may be toelis in knowing who the thief was to try to get the item  back    but not always will it be so  important as to fall into the category of  *Lo sa'amod al dam re'acha*

In  both cases the main criteria of having to force yourself to speak up but not only out of hate is the question of  does this situation fall into *Lo sa'amod al dam re'acha*