# Is one allowed to say that a girl is simpleminded when giving shidduch information?

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, shidduchim-dating, sheker-false, emes-truth-honesty

If a person is trying to help another make a shidduch (assist in arranging a potential marriage), they may know that a particular boy would be looking for a smart girl. If the person has information that she is not so smart, are they allowed to volunteer that information, or would that be slanderous? Is the halacha different if they are specifically asked if she is smart?

Comment: Very nice question (after the edit)! I'm pretty sure the answer is spelled out in sefer chofetz chaim. The general advice is to avoid answering such a question. But one should ask a rav in cases like this, because sometimes one has to volunteer the information, and it can be a heavy question.

Comment: @Mordechai No, still not a very nice question. This isn’t the place for a question which should be asked to one’s Rav.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93146/lashon-hara-ltoeles-with-ulterior-motives

Comment: OK, the answer is ask your rabbi.

Comment: Edited to make it an abstract question, not a specific request for psak or advice.  Recommend reopening.

Comment: והשבת it is permitted

Comment: LOL! Why would some one say a woman is "simple minded". That is like calling her stupid. So, Straightforward: This word implies that the person doesn't over complicate matters. Or you can say she is "down to earth" or Naive: Lacking experience or sophistication in certain areas.
Innocent: Not having extensive knowledge about certain topics.
Uncomplicated: Preferring straightforwardness and not overthinking things.
Trusts her instincts: Relying more on feelings than on analytical thought. Or maybe even "feeble" -- "though feeble she is woman drive for hashem"